# Pass label for field to WTForms __init__

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to pass the label for a form field as an argument to the form's `__init__`. Right now I get a `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` error.

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, label_t, **kw):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.label_t = label_t

    name = StringField(self.label_t, validators=[DataRequired()])

f = MyForm("test1", csrf_enabled=False)
```

I also tried putting the name variable into the init function, 
but I get `AttributeError: 'UnboundField' object has no attribute '__call__'`.

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, label_t, **kw):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.label_t = label_t
        self.name = StringField(self.label_t, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

How can I pass the label for a field to `__init__`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access `self` from a class attribute which is the reason for the `NameError`. If you want to set the label of your field on `__init__` just set the `label` attribute of the instance:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):

    def __init__(self, label_t, **kw):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.name.label = label_t

    name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense :)

Comment: Maybe WTForms has changed since this was written, but I had to set `self.name.label.text` instead of `self.name.label`, using WTForms v2.2.1.